# how to understand the manifold with boundary jet bundle and cotangent bundle with boundary

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, lagrangian-submanifolds, cotangent-bundles

Suppose that $M\subset (W^{2n},\omega)$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold with smooth boundary $\partial M$, where $(W,\omega)$ is a $2n$-dimensional Kähler manifold and boundary with contact type structure, which ensure that $\partial W$ has a contact 1-form induced by $\omega$.

**My questions are:**

1. How can we understand the structure of $\partial T^*(M)$ and characterize its normal vector field in $T^*M$? Can it be related to the relative normal field of $\nu\in T_{\partial M}M$?
2. What is the relation between $\partial T^*(M)$ and jet bundle $T^*(\partial M)\times \mathbb{R}$ with standard contact 1-form, and when can $T^*(\partial M\times \mathbb{R})$ and $T^*(M)$ be identified?
3. What if $M$ is a Lagrangian submanifold?

Many thanks for any comments or examples.

Comment: Wouldn't $\partial T^*(M)$ be the same as $T^*(M)|_{\partial M}$ and there is a canonical projection from $T^*(M)|_{\partial M}$ to $T^*(\partial M)$ by restricting?

Comment: Thanks for comments. You mean view $\partial T^*(M)$ as $T^*(M)|_{\partial M}$ bundle over $\partial M$ with same $n$ dimensional fiber as $T^*(M)$ ? Is the normal vector field of $T^*(M)|_{\partial M}$ be induced from $\nu\in T_{\partial M}M$? say, for a section $s\in T^*(M)$  of cotangent bundle, is the normal vector field at point $(x,s(x))\in T^*(M)|_{\partial M} $( here, $x\in\partial M$)  in $T^*(M)$ be $(\nu_x,\nu_x \lrcorner \nabla s)$?

Comment: Yes, for your first question. I don’t quite understand your second question. What do you mean with the normal vector field? There is a canonical 1 dimensional subspace of $T^*M|_{\partial M}$ consisting of those covectors that vanish when paired with tangent vectors of the boundary. A generator of this subspace might be called a normal covector.

Comment: I wonder whether the normal covector of $T^*M_{\partial M}$ (view it as submanifold and boundary of $T^*M$ ) has some relation with the normal covector of $\partial M$ ?